# Calling a function from another file into another function C++

Tags: c++, function, enums

I have some header files which host functions and in other enums.

So in file Lexer.h, I have a function called `getNextToken()` which returns a token and in this function I need to call a function called `reservedLookup(string tokenString)` found in token.h

reservedWords is another header file called `reservedWords.h` which has enum declarations of the reserved Words

This function is found in token.h

```
reservedWords reservedLookup (string tokenString)
{
        for(rIt = reservedMap.begin(); rIt!= reservedMap.end(); rIt++)
        {
            if(tokenString == (rIt->first))
            {
                return rIt->second;
            }

        }
}
```

in lexer.h I tried using this in private (and even in public:) :

```
reservedWords reservedLookup(string tokenString);
```

it compiles, but when in function  `Token* getNextToken()` I use

```
int tokenType = reservedLookup(strBuffer);
```

it gives me an error stating:

```
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5Lexer12getNextTokenEv[__ZN5Lexer12getNextTokenEv]+0x371)||undefined reference to `Lexer::reservedLookup(std::string)'|
```

I don't want my compiler to read reservedLookup as part of `Lexer::reservedLookup(string str)` but as `Token::reservedLookup(string str)`

Is there any way I can do it?

---

EDIT:

### Token.h

```
class Token
{
       .....
       .....
public:

    void reservedDeclare ()
    {
         // iterator used for looping through reservedWords

        //Taking care of the Reserved Words first

        reservedMap["function"] =  reservedWords::tkfunction;

        //if - then - else - while - halt
        reservedMap["if"] = reservedWords::tkif;
        reservedMap["else"] = reservedWords::tkelse;
        reservedMap["while"] = reservedWords::tkwhile;
        reservedMap["halt"] = reservedWords::tkhalt;

        //and, or, not, true, else
        reservedMap["and"] = reservedWords::tkand;
        reservedMap["or"] = reservedWords::tkor;
        reservedMap["not"] = reservedWords::tknot;
        reservedMap["true"] = reservedWords::tktrue;
        reservedMap["false"] = reservedWords::tkfalse;

        //sets and read/write
        reservedMap["set"] = reservedWords::tkset;
        reservedMap["let"] = reservedWords::tklet;
        reservedMap["read"] = reservedWords::tkread;
        reservedMap["write"] = reservedWords::tkwrite;

        //variable type
        reservedMap["int"] = reservedWords::tkint;
        reservedMap["char"] = reservedWords::tkchar;
        reservedMap["bool"] = reservedWords::tkbool;
        reservedMap["real"] = reservedWords::tkreal;
        reservedMap["string"] = reservedWords::tkstring;
        reservedMap["unit"] = reservedWords::tkunit;


    }

reservedWords reservedLookup (string tokenString)
{
        for(rIt = reservedMap.begin(); rIt!= reservedMap.end(); rIt++)
        {
            if(tokenString == (rIt->first))
            {
                return rIt->second;
            }

        }
}
```

### reservedWords.h

```
#ifndef RESERVEDWORDS_H_INCLUDED
#define RESERVEDWORDS_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <vector> //std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::find

using namespace std;

/**
        All the reserved words used by the compiler

*/


    /**
        This file contains all the keywords or reserved words or reserved Symbols used by the compiler
        In the lexer, we will check whether the string we are passing is either a Reserved word
        or it is actually and identifier
    */

    enum reservedWords
    {
        tkfunction,
        tkif,
        tkelse,
        tkwhile,
        tkhalt,

        tkand,
        tkor,
        tknot,
        tktrue,
        tkfalse,

        tkset,
        tklet,
        tkread,
        tkwrite,

        tkint,
        tkchar,
        tkbool,
        tkreal,
        tkstring,
        tkunit,

        tkreservedWord,
        tkidentifier


    };

    #endif // RESERVEDWORDS_H_INCLUDED
```

---

### PARTIAL Code of Lexer.h

```
class Lexer
{
   private:
   string strBuffer ="";//holds the current characters that have been read and waiting to be matched
   int tokenType = 0;
   reservedWords reservedLookup(string tokenString); // THIS DOES NOT WORK. SEES IT AS Lexer::reservedLookup
  ....
  ....
  ...
  ...

  tokenType = reservedLookup(strBuffer); // GIVES ME ERROR BECAUSE OF ABOVE
```

Comment: Please make it clear when your code samples are inside a class definition or other context.

Comment: @aschepler Check the edit, see if it helps... LEXER.H and TOKEN.H are both in a class. ReservedWords no, just enum

Comment: In the partial code of Lexer.h, where you have "THIS DOES NOT WORK" commented... Is that a class member function declaration within class Lexer?  If it is _not_, why is it there?  If it _is_, why doesn't it have a return value?

Comment: @jeffrey_t_b sorry that should be read as `reservedWords reservedlookup (string tokenString)` , I tried to make another header function to call the one in token.h (as I've seen on other tutorials) but it didn't help. all the other tutorials consisted of having .cpp with it

Comment: Is `tokenType = reservedLookup(strBuffer);` inside a function definition?  If you want it to call `Token::reservedLookup`, what `Token` object to you want it to use?

Comment: `tokenType = reservedLookup(strBuffer)` is found inside function called `Token* getNextToken()` which returns an enum. Token is an enum, which can return reservedWords and so. I want to call reservedLookup which is found in Token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this part of your code first:

```
class Token
{
  ...
public:
  ...
  reservedWords reservedLookup (string tokenString)
  {       // start of function body
    for(rIt = reservedMap.begin(); rIt!= reservedMap.end(); rIt++)
    {
        if(tokenString == (rIt->first))
        {
            return rIt->second;
        }

    }
  }       // end of function body
  ...
};
```

In this file you have declared a function whose fully-scoped name is `Token::reservedLookup`. (If you're unfamiliar with the term "fully scoped", OK; for our purposes here, the important thing is that this is a specific way of naming this function.) We can write `Token::` at the front of this name because this function is a member of the class `Token`.  You have also *defined* the function by providing a function body (the code enclosed in braces `{` and `}`). I have added comments on the lines where the function body begins and ends.

So far, so good. Now, this function is an ordinary member of the class `Token`, not a "static" function, so in order to call it, you must first have an object of type `Token`, and then you can call this function on that object, for example by writing code like this inside some other function:

```
Token token;
token.reservedDeclare();
reservedWords word = token.reservedLookup("read");
```

Now comes the part where things get confused. You wrote this code:

```
class Lexer
{
private:
  ...
  reservedWords reservedLookup(string tokenString);
  ...
};
```

What this does is to declare a *different* function from the first one. This function's fully-scoped name is `Lexer::reservedLookup`. You have not provided any *definition* of the function, however (neither here, nor apparently anywhere else).  So when you are within the code of the `Lexer` class and you write a line such as this,

```
tokenType = reservedLookup(strBuffer);
```

the compiler interprets this in the way the C++ language specification says it should, which is that this should be a call to the function `reservedLookup` that belongs to the class of the same function where this call appeared. In short, it is a call to `Lexer::reservedLookup`. Since you never defined that function, it is impossible to produce the code that calls the function correctly, and therefore you have an error.

So you probably do not want to define `Lexer::reservedLookup` at all. If you are not calling `Token::reservedLookup` from within one of the functions of the class `Token` itself, you may provide an *object* of type `Token` so that you may call the function, as I did in my example. Alternatively, you might want to make your definition of the function static so that you can call it this way, without requiring an object of type `Token`:

```
reservedWords word = Token::reservedLookup("read");
```

In order to make this work as desired, however, you would also have to make `reservedDeclare` a static function and make `reservedMap` a static variable of `Token`, or make some other changes so that the data used by `Token::reservedLookup` exists independently of a specific object of type `Token`.

You may also want to look at the answers to this question: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read a recommended book to help understand the terminology of the language better so that you can get better advice about your programs.

Comment: Thanks mate! really good explanation helped me with a lot of stuff. Will try some things out

Comment: so when functions are `ClassName::Function` they are Fully scoped right? sry if asking again

Comment: @DodoSerebro: Technically, no. For instance, there's `std::string::size` where `std` is a namespace, and `string` the class, and `size` the function. A name is fully qualified if it includes all surrounding classes and namespaces.

Comment: As pointed out by @MSalters, it is not always the case that a fully-scoped name has only one `::`.  In the code in the question. I merely assumed there was no additional scoping defined in the parts of the source files we didn't see. For example, I assumed you didn't write anything like `namespace parsing {` as the last thing before your definition of `class Token`, because that would have made the fully-scoped function name `parsing::Token::reservedLookup`.